# Determine which of the following sets are subspaces of ℝ³

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let 
$$W =[{ (x, y, z);\sqrt{ x^2 + y^2+z^2};x, y,z\space \in \mathbb {R}}]$$

Prove that W is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

How could I resolve subspace. I tried something like this:
$${\sqrt{ 5^2 + 3^2+2^2}=\sqrt{ 25+9+4}=38\space}$$
But i don't fully understand  what to do then.

Comment: Do not panic if you can't solve it! probably there is a typo in the book.

Answer (score 1):

The set $W$ is not well defined, something is missing, as for example

$$W =[{ (x, y, z);\color{red}{\sqrt{ x^2 + y^2+z^2}=1};x, y,z\space \epsilon \mathbb {R}}]$$